# Using Python Multiprocessing with Gtk3 GUI on Windows 10

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gtk

I want to use Python 3 multiprocessing  with the GUI based on GTK 3. I am using Windows 10 OS.
I want to calculate `result=x*x` by button click. There will be 4 instance of this calculation operation. In other terms, when user clicks button1, 4 instance of `result=x*x` calculation will be performed for `x=1, 2, 3, 4` values by using multiprocessing.

I have tried several things but python opens multiple  GUI windows on Windows OS.

How can i do this?

My code is simplified as below: (It opens 4 new GUI windows).

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
import os
import multiprocessing

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file('test.glade')
builder.get_objects()
window1 = builder.get_object('window1')
button1 = builder.get_object('button1')

class Signals:
    def on_window1_destroy(self, widget):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def on_button1_clicked(self, widget):
        def main():
            work_l=[1,2,3,4]
            with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
                pool.map(work, work_l)

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()

def work(x):
    result=x*x
    print(result)

builder.connect_signals(Signals())
window1.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: First, multithreading before multiprocessing. Did you read the document? [threading — Thread-based parallelism — Python 3.9.1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: I have tried several thing but python opens multiple  GUI windows on Windows OS.

Comment: Could you add what you tried to to the post?

Comment: I have added one of them which i could run the code without error.

Comment: Did you mean multiple GUI windows for including a terminal window? Result of calculations must appears in there?

Comment: Not including terminal window. I have a GUI generated in Glade. It is a simple GUI. Only a window and a button on it. If i click on it it makes calculation but also opens 4 more windows (window with a button that i mentioned above). 4 is number of workers defined in the code. I read results from Pycharm output. There is difference of python multiprocessing behavior on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Measures are clear but I have few clue for the reasons! GTK written in ancient complicated C so I can't pursue codes quite easily. Though, to take making processes out from class definition  to outside, it will make the code work. In order to do it, you have to deal with `multiprocessing.Process` directly without `Pool`...

Comment: My job is not pogramming and i am very new to python. I did not understand what did you mean in your last 2 sentences. As far as i know, using pool is useful and advised in some sources because i do not need to join processes and no need to do something else.